# Method returns class reference even after termination

Tags: c#, garbage-collection

I have just started learning C#7.0 from the documentation. I learnt that Class is a reference type. But how can a method return a reference to an object that is already destroyed.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            Test b = GetObj();
            Console.WriteLine(b.val);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
        public class Test
        {
            public int val;
        }
        public static Test GetObj()
        {
            Test t = new Test();
            t.val = 100;
            return t;
        }
    }

}
```

Here, method `GetObj` creates a Test object, and returns it. According to documentation, only a reference to it is returned. So after the function call, `t` should be collected as garbage, and so `b` should reference nothing.

But the code still prints `100`. Why?

Comment: Think about why this would be such a bad idea _if_ the language gave you a pointer and then disposed of the object it was pointing to. There wouldn't even be a point in returning the reference at all if that was the case...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> So after the function call,"t" should be collected as garbage, and so "b" should reference nothing.

No. The garbage collector knows how many variables are still referencing that instance, so it isn't garbage collected at all. When there are no variables referencing the instance any more, the garbage collector will kick in.

Comment: and garbage collector doesn't instantly collects, it periodically checks for objects eligible to be collected

Comment: Yup. There are ways to make the GC a little more eager, but you can't really rely on running it at will.

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly.

When `GetObj()` is done executing, what is destroyed is the pointer `t`, not the actual object of type `Test`.

As you go up the stack, `b` now points to the object, so the object is not collected because there is a reference to it.

When `Main()` is done executing, the pointer `b` will go out of scope and nothing will point to the object anymore so the garbage collector will be able to pick it up (in this case, the end of the program execution).